# DIV and BCOR setting in KOMA (best practices)

Tags: margins, koma-script, geometry, best-practices, typearea

I have been playing around and I now realize it is possible to set the type area using a KOMA class by a couple of ways, and I'll like to know which is the correct one.

```
\documentclass[%
a4paper,
12pt,
%BCOR=3mm, %<---Should I load it here or in 'marito.sty'?
%DIV=12, %<---Should I load it here or in 'marito.sty'?
twoside,%default
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{marito}

\begin{document}
Recto Page
\newpage
Verso Page
\end{document}
```

**First option:** I know that KOMA default is `a4paper`, and if I set the font to `12pt` it automatically defaults to `DIV=12`.

**Second option:** I know I can set both `BCOR` and `DIV` directly as an optional argument to the KOMA-class `scrbook`.

**Third option:** Since I'm using my own `.sty` file, I can set `BCOR` and `DIV` with `\typearea[3mm]{12}` (see marito.sty)

**Fourth option:** Also, because of the use of my `marito.sty` file, I can set `BCOR` and `DIV` with `\KOMAoptions{DIV=12,BCOR=12mm}`

This is what is contained in `marito.sty`:

```
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\typearea[3mm]{12} % <---Should I use this one
%\KOMAoptions{DIV=12,BCOR=3mm} %<--- or this one?
\RequirePackage{lmodern}

\RequirePackage[pass,showframe]{geometry} % Just to show the frame around the textbox
```

As mentioned in the comments, I have tested all possibilities and they all seem to work.  The question I have is what's the right way to set the `BCOR` and `DIV` when you are using a custom `.sty` file?

Comment: As far as i know, loading `geometry` trashes the default KOMA settings. Maybe package `showframe` is better.

Comment: @Johannes_B even though I'm explicitly `passing` every possible command (except, of course, for `showframe`)?

Comment: I am not sure. If you set `DIV` and `BCOR` after loading geometry, you might need `\recalctypearea`. But, as said before, i am not sure.

Comment: @Johannes_B I know for sure these four options work (I have tested them all).  I don't have *an issue* per se, I just want to know which one is the right one to call DIV and BCOR when using a custom .sty file

Comment: `\documentclass[
BCOR=90mm
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
Recto Page
\newpage
Verso Page
\end{document}
`

Try uncommenting package `geometry`, maybe package `showframe` helps

Comment: @Johannes_B If `geometry` trashes the settings, why uncomment it?

Comment: @cfr To see the difference in the output in the minimal example i posted.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Option `pass` of package `geometry` should keep the current settings.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Ah, `pass`, i wasn't aware of that. Thanks for the clarification and sorry for the noise.

Comment: @Johannes_B With the help of the `layouts` package I was able to confirm that all the four options mentioned in the question provided the same answer...  Once again, this is a `best practice` question :)

Comment: I wasn't aware of your `pass`ing. With that being said, you can completely ignore `geometry` (except option `showframe`, also available as a package). \par Since DIV and BCOR are provided by typearea (part of KOMA-script) all options should be completely equivalent (except for the first one, expecting the standard means one degree of freedom)

Comment: I don't know if this applies here, but in some cases there are advantages to passing options directly to the class rather than setting them later. (And sometimes the reverse.) This is because, *other* packages may also make use of those options if they know about them, and they may pick up the class options. (This is why passing `a4paper` to `article` and then loading `geometry` with no options gets you A4.) For example, this is certainly true of language options (`british` or whatever).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Note that the KOMA-Script class loads the package `typearea` itself and the text block and the margins are calculated immediately for the first time.

The first and the second version are the same (if the standard value is chosen in the second): the text body and the margins are calculated onces.

Third version: There is a second calculation of the page layout when `\typearea[<bcor>]{<div>}` is called. Already done changes of line spacing and `KOMAoptions` regarding to the page layout are taken into account.

And there is also a difference between your third and fourth version. From the KOMA-Script manual:

> If both BCOR and DIV need changing, then it is recommended to use
>   \typearea, since then the text block and margins are recalculated only
>   once. With \KOMAoptions{DIV=DIV ,BCOR=BCOR } the text block and
>   margins are recalculated once for the change to DIV and again for the
>   change to BCOR.

---

I suggest to set the `BCOR` option as an argument of the KOMA-class because it depends from the document itself, especially from the number of pages.

---

Note that the predefined `DIV` value is only a compromise and does not take into account the font chosen. I suggest to use `DIV=calc` instead of the predefined value.

Here is an simple example to demonstrate the difference:

```
\documentclass[BCOR=3mm,12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\KOMAoptions{DIV=calc}% recalculate the page layout with a calculated DIV value
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

The following snippet of the log file shows that the calculated `DIV` value is 9 instead of the predefined value 12:

```
...
(C:\LocalPrograms\LocalTeXMFs\koma-script-current\tex\latex\koma-script\typeare
a.sty
Package: typearea 2014/04/09 v3.13.1756 KOMA-Script package (type area)

Package typearea, 2014/04/09 v3.13.1756 KOMA-Script package (type area)
                  Copyright (C) Frank Neukam, 1992-1994
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm, 1994-

\ta@bcor=\skip41
\ta@div=\count79
\ta@hblk=\skip42
\ta@vblk=\skip43
\ta@temp=\skip44
\footheight=\skip45
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 12
(typearea)             BCOR = 8.53581pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 441.7291pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = -4%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 25.89203pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = -14.65317pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 635.5pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -41.72441pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 18.125pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 21.75pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 12.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 50.75pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 14.5pt
(typearea)              on input line 1332.
)
...
...
DIV calculation for typearea with good linewidth.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+lmr on input line 4.
(C:\LocalPrograms\MiKTeX2.9\tex\latex\lm\t1lmr.fd
File: t1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 9
(typearea)             BCOR = 8.53581pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 392.64809pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = 0%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 58.6127pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = 1.70717pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 577.5pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -18.25089pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 18.125pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 21.75pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 12.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 50.75pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 14.5pt
(typearea)              on input line 4.
...
```

But as I have already mentioned the KOMA-Script class loads the package `typearea` itself and at that moment the class option `DIV=calc` is evaluated to a value according to the LaTeX standard font.

After loading a package with a significant different font (`lmodern` is similar to the standard fonts) you have to (re)calculate this value using `\KOMAoptions{DIV=calc}` or `\typearea[current]{calc}`. Instead you can say `\recalctypearea` if `DIV=calc` was already set for the previous calculation of the text block and the margins. `\recalctypearea` is an abbreviated command for `\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}` or `\typearea[current]{last}`.

In addition, a recalculation by the `typearea` package is necessary if you change `KOMAoptions` regarding the page layout (`headheight`, `headinclude` etc.) and also if you change the line spreading (to ensure that the `\textheight` less `\topskip` is a multiple of `\baselineskip`).

---

In conclusion, I suggest:

Use `\documentclass[BCOR=<bcor>,DIV=calc,...]{scrbook}` in the main file.

If there are significant changes of font or any changes of the line spacing or the `KOMAoptions` regarding the page layout in your `marito.sty` file, use `\recalctypearea` after this changes are done.

Note that you find all values determined by typearea in the log file. If necessary you can set a moderately adjusted value `<div>` by `\documentclass[BCOR=<bcor>,DIV=<div>,...]{scrbook}`. Then the command `\recalctypearea` will also use this manually chosen `<div>` value.

Comment: I am sorry, but I would be grateful if you could help me produce the desired output in [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/322024/2288) without using geometry package as in the accepted answer.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou If you have special requirements for the page margins like 2cm for the bottom and 2cm for the right margin like in your linked question then you have to use package `geometry`.

Comment: I see; I thought it could be done using `typearea` only. Thanks for your clarification.