# KOMA-Script: Why does "DIV=calc" destroy the initial geometry?

Tags: margins, koma-script, typearea

Why does the `DIV=calc`-command modify the whole layout geometry, even if the binding correction `BCOR` is set to `0mm`?

Let's have a look at two simple examples to explain my question.

---

### **1. Example**

In the first example, I completely disactivate the `BCOR` and the `DIV=calc` commands by commenting them out. The result will be a harmonious looking layout with nice borders.

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE)**:

```
\documentclass[twoside=false]{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}

% \KOMAoptions{BCOR=0mm}
% \KOMAoptions{DIV=calc}

\begin{document}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Nice layout with disactivated BCOR/DIV=calc and initial geometry.]

---

### **2. Example**

However, if I switch on the `DIV=calc`-command even with `BCOR=0mm`, the whole layout is getting changed. The result will be a strongly modified geometry with (in my eyes) too wide and inharmonious border widths.

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE)**:

```
\documentclass[twoside=false]{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\KOMAoptions{BCOR=0mm}
\KOMAoptions{DIV=calc}

\begin{document}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Modified layout with activated BCOR and initial geometry.]

---

**What is the reason for this behavior?**

Why does the whole layout change, even with `0mm` in `BCOR`? I think the initial layout without `DIV=calc` is looking way more natural, doesn't it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you do not set option `DIV` as class option package `typearea` is loaded using `DIV=default`. That means: either there exists a default value (only for a4 paper and the fontsizes 10pt, 11pt or 12pt) or `DIV=calc` is used automatically.

Your example does not set `paper`, `fontsize` or `DIV`, so the defaults `paper=a4`, `fontsize=11pt`, `DIV=default` are used. This results in the preset value `DIV=10`.

With `DIV=calc` package `typearea` recalculates the `DIV` value depending on the current font to get a recommended number of characters per line. In your example this is `DIV=8`. You can find this value in the log file.

If you do not want a change of `DIV` while the page layout is recalculated, do not use `DIV=calc`. Replace it by `DIV=current` (current value of `DIV`) or `DIV=last` (last argument of option `DIV` - this could be a number or a symbolic value like `default`).

But if you change `BCOR` in the preamble the recalculation of the page layout is already done using `DIV=last`. In your example this would be `DIV=default` resulting in `DIV=10`. So there is no need to set `DIV` again. See also [DIV and BCOR setting in KOMA (best practices)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183839/43317).

Note that `\recalctypearea` recalculates the page layout using options `BCOR=current` and `DIV=last`.

If the margins should be smaller set a larger `DIV` value i.e. `DIV=12`.

If you need special margins you could set KOMA-Script option `usegeometry` and load package `geometry` to change the margins.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your nice help! You said: "[...] if you change `BCOR` in the preamble the recalculation of the page layout is already done using `DIV=last`. In your example this would be `DIV=default` resulting in `DIV=10`. **So there is no need to set `DIV` again**" ----> That means: If I already specified `BCOR=10mm` in the preamble, the page layout will be recalculated by `DIV=last` automatically and there is no need anymore to add an additional `DIV=calc`? So only `BCOR` is required and the recalculation will be done by `DIV=last` automatically in that case?

Comment: @Dave Yes. Have a look in the log file. There you can see the values/results of the first calculation (when the class loads `typearea`). Later on you see the values/results of the recalculation (when you set `BCOR=0mm` by `\KOMAoptions`). If you add `DIV=last`there would be a second recalculation even if you use `\KOMAoptions{BCOR=0mm,DIV=last}`. In your example the values/results of both recalculations will be the same.

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR: `DIV=calc` is supposed to alter layout as it is an option for page layout construction.**

Just my opinion on the last question: No, it doesn't look more natural without `DIV=calc`. At least if you are used to this setting.

But to clarify what the purpose of both settings is (more or less to be read in the KOMA documentation):

- `BCOR` sets a binding correction, which is a horizontal shift of the text block away from the inner margin.
- `DIV` now uses the remaining page (without binding correction) to divide the page into equally high parts. It does the same on the horizontal axis (equally wide parts). The top margin is the uppermost stripe, the bottom margin the two bottom-most stripes. It does the same with the inner-most stripe (like top) and the two outer-most stripes (like bottom).

So there are some predefined divisions of the page (`DIV` ranging from 6 to 15 [stripes per page]). `DIV=calc` is now supposed to choose the most aesthetic page layout automatically. As soon as you do `\recalctypearea` (or alter one of the aforementioned KOMA options) it will try to reduce the line width so that not too many characters will make up a line (tradition in typography, there are values like 66 characters per line as a rule of thumb).

There are other methods for automatic calculation like `DIV=classic`, but you seemingly do not want to do this.

Now to your question: As I've just explained, `DIV` is supposed to change page layout. Hence setting it will result in different margins and a drastically altered visual appearance, which aims at helping the reader focus, because on paper shorter lines are better to read than lines of 80-100 characters.

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice explanation! Unfortunately it is only possible to select one answer as the "final" answer - I would love to select your answer as well!